# Prove that there exists $c>0$ such that $\operatorname{supp}(f)\cap K \subset \{x \in K:|f(x)| \geq c\}+\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}:|x|<\varepsilon\}.$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, smooth-functions

Let $f \in C^k(\Omega)$ and $K$ be a compact subset of $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and consider $\varepsilon>0$. I'm trying to prove that there exists $c>0$ such that
$$\operatorname{supp}(f)\cap K \subset \{x \in K:|f(x)| \geq c\}+\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}:|x|<\varepsilon\}.$$

I think we have to use the fact that $f$ is continuous and thus has a minimum point in compact $K$. But I don't know exactly how.

This is a afirmation from Trèves book, Topological Vector Spaces, Distributions and Kernels.

[image: This is a afirmation from Trèves book.]

Comment: I guess since $f$ is continuous and $K$ is compact we can make the set $\lbrace x \in K:|f(x)|≥c \rbrace$ to be equal to $K$, because we can choose $c$ to be the minimum of $f$ in that compacr set. Then we always have $A \cap K \subseteq K$ for all $A \subset \Omega$.

Comment: The problem is that this constant can be $0$, and I need it strictly positive.

Comment: Maybe the $c > 0$ condition could help us with the unit ball at the right side of the inequality.

Comment: I don't think this is true as stated. Probably you also want to assume that $f$ never vanishes. Otherwise consider $K$ equal to two balls which are more than $\varepsilon$ apart from each other and $f$ vanishes on one of the balls.

Comment: Never mind, I am just stupid. You intersect with the support of the function. Then it follows directly from uniform continuity. By uniform continuity you know that there exists a constant $d$ such that if you change $x$ by at most $\varepsilon$, then the function will change at most by $d$.

Comment: Does $A + \left\{x \in \mathbf{R}^{n} ;|x| \leqslant \varepsilon\right\}$ means "we add up to $\varepsilon$ in all directions to any x in A" ?

Comment: @VictorHugo I was wrong about uniform continuity. Did not think it through, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assertion is not quite true. There is one case in which it is wrong, and that is when $K$ contains boundary points of $\operatorname{supp} (f)$ but no points with $f(x) \neq 0$ near such a boundary point. The extreme case of that is when $K = \{ x \in \Omega : f(x) = 0\}$. Then $K \cap \operatorname{supp} (f) = \partial K \neq \varnothing$, but
$$\{ x \in K : \lvert f(x)\rvert \geqslant c\} + \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \lvert x\rvert \leqslant \varepsilon\} = \varnothing + \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \lvert x\rvert \leqslant \varepsilon\} = \varnothing$$
for all $c > 0$.

Such things often happen when one only gives an outline of the arguments and avoids writing out all the cumbersome nitty-gritty details. One thinks of the typical situation and overlooks possible pathologies. Nevertheless, at the bottom of this answer I will only give an outline of how I think the proof can be corrected. I believe I haven't overlooked anything, and the missing details can be correctly filled in, but I'm not inclined to fill them in myself. (I don't know of a place where the part of the theorem for which Trèves' proof is incorrect is needed. If that part turns out important too, as the first part is, that would be a reason to dive into the details.)

<s>Probably this is not a serious problem and the proof works if instead of $K \cap \operatorname{supp} (f)$ we consider
$$\operatorname{supp} (f\lvert_K) = \overline{\{ x \in K : f(x) \neq 0\}}\,,$$
but I didn't find the passage in question on a quick leafing through the book, so I can't be sure of that.</s>

Unfortunately, the proof cannot be fixed that easily. But I'll keep the argument for $\operatorname{supp}(f\lvert_K)$ anyway.

Let us work with $\operatorname{supp} (f\lvert_K)$ instead of $K \cap \operatorname{supp} (f)$. For every $c > 0$, consider the set
$$U_c := \{ x \in K : \lvert f(x)\rvert \geqslant c\} + \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \lvert x\rvert < \varepsilon\}\,.$$
Since the second summand is open, $U_c$ is an open set, and it is obviously contained in the analogous set where the inequality in the second summand is non-strict too. Thus it suffices to show that there is a $c > 0$ with $\operatorname{supp} (f\lvert_K) \subset U_c$.

I claim that the family $\{U_c : c > 0\}$ is an open cover of $\operatorname{supp} (f\lvert_K)$. If we accept that claim for the moment, the proof is quickly finished. Since $\operatorname{supp} (f\lvert_K)$ is compact, this cover has a finite subcover, i.e. there is a finite set $\{ c_k : 1 \leqslant k \leqslant m\}$ of (strictly) positive numbers with
$$\operatorname{supp} (f\lvert_K) \subset \bigcup_{k = 1}^m U_{c_k}\,.$$
From the definition of the $U_c$ it is immediate that $c < c' \implies U_{c'} \subset U_c$, and hence we have
$$\operatorname{supp} (f\lvert_K) \subset U_{c_0}$$
for $c_0 = \min\:\{ c_k : 1 \leqslant k \leqslant m\} > 0$.

It remains to prove the claim. Let $x_0 \in \operatorname{supp} (f\lvert_K)$. Then
$$\gamma := \max \{ \lvert f(x)\rvert : x \in K, \lvert x - x_0\rvert \leqslant \varepsilon/2\} > 0$$
since $\{x \in K : \lvert x - x_0\rvert \leqslant \varepsilon/2\}$ is a $K$-neighbourhood of $x_0$, so by definition of the support $f$ cannot vanish identically there. But then clearly $x_0 \in U_{\gamma}$.

---

Before coming to the fix, I'll note another mistake in Trèves' proof. Directly before the marked part, Trèves wrote

> If a compact set $K$ is contained in some open set $\Omega_{j-1}$, we know that $K\cap \operatorname{supp} f_j$ is contained in the neighborhood of order $1/j$ of $K \cap \operatorname{supp}(h_j f) = K \cap \operatorname{supp} f$.

This isn't necessarily correct. The construction only guarantees that $K \cap \operatorname{supp}(f_j)$ is contained in the intersection of $K$ with the $1/j$-neighbourhood of $\operatorname{supp}(f)$. It can be that $K$ lies outside the support of $f$ but intersects the support of $f_j$.

This one however is easily fixable. Let $\varepsilon > 0$. If $K \subset \Omega_m$, then *for all sufficiently large* $j$ the assertion that $K \cap \operatorname{supp} (f_j)$ is contained in the $\varepsilon$-neighbourhood of $K \cap \operatorname{supp} (f)$ holds. It need not hold for $j = m+1$ (or $j = m + r$ for any fixed $r$), but from some point on it holds. For, let
$$M_{\varepsilon} = \{ x \in K : \operatorname{dist}(x, K \cap \operatorname{supp}(f)) \geqslant \varepsilon\}\,.$$
Then $M_{\varepsilon}$ is compact, and every $x \in \varepsilon$ has a neighbourhood (relative to $\mathbb{R}^n$) on which $f$ vanishes identically - otherwise $x$ would lie in $\operatorname{supp}(f)$. Let
$$r = \min_{x \in M_{\varepsilon}} \operatorname{dist}\bigl(x, \operatorname{supp} (f)\bigr)\,.$$
Then $M_{\varepsilon} \cap \operatorname{supp}(f_j) = \varnothing$, i.e. $K \cap \operatorname{supp}(f_j)$ is contained in the $\varepsilon$-neighbourhood of $K \cap \operatorname{supp}(f)$, for $j > 1/r$.

The theorem to be proved is

> **Theorem** $15.3$. Let $0 \leqslant k \leqslant +\infty$, $\Omega$, be an open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Any function $f \in \mathscr{C}^k(\Omega)$ is the limit of a sequence $\{f_j\}$ $(j = 1,2,\dotsc$) of $\mathscr{C}^{\infty}$ functions with compact support in $\Omega$ such that, for each compact subset $K$ of $\Omega$, the set $K \cap \operatorname{supp} f_j$ converges to $K \cap \operatorname{supp} f$.

The convergence of sets is in the sense of the Hausdorff distance here.

The proof begins with taking a normal exhaustion of $\Omega$, that is, a sequence $\Omega_0, \Omega_1, \dotsc$ of open subsets of $\Omega$ such that each $\Omega_j$ is relatively compact in $\Omega_{j+1}$, and $\Omega$ is the union of the $\Omega_j$. Then smooth ($\mathscr{C}^{\infty}$) cut-off functions $h_j$ are constructed, such that $h_j$ is identically $1$ on $\Omega_{j-1}$ and $\operatorname{supp} h_j \subset \Omega_j$.

As a first step, the functions $h_j f$ are considered. These form a sequence in $\mathscr{C}_c^k(\Omega)$ that converges to $f$ in $\mathscr{C}^k(\Omega)$.

In the case $k = +\infty$ we can take $f_j = h_j f$. Then we have $K \cap \operatorname{supp}(f_j) = K\cap \operatorname{supp}(f)$ if $K \subset \Omega_{j-1}$, hence also the second part of the theorem's assertion.

For $k < +\infty$, $h_j f$ is generically only $\mathscr{C}^k$, hence we must approximate that by a $\mathscr{C}_c^{\infty}$ function. That is of course done by convolving $h_j f$ with $\rho_{\delta_j}$ for sufficiently small $\delta_j$. One picks $\delta_j < 1/j$, so that the support of $\varphi_j := \rho_{\delta_j} \ast (h_j f)$ is contained in the $1/j$-neighbourhood of the support of $h_j f$, and additionally $\delta_j$ must be small enough that all of the partial derivatives of $\varphi_j$ of order $\leqslant k$ are within $1/j$ of the corresponding partial derivative of $h_j f$ on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $\operatorname{supp} (\varphi_j) \subset \Omega$.

Then it is clear that $\{\varphi_j\}$ is a sequence in $\mathscr{C}_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ that converges to $f$ in $\mathscr{C}^k(\Omega)$. Trèves takes $f_j = \varphi_j$, but due to the issues pointed out above I do not see a way to prove the convergence property of the supports without modifying $\varphi_j$ slightly.

Things work out nicely if we have $\operatorname{supp} (h_j f) \subset \operatorname{supp} (\varphi_j)$. Then we always have $K \cap \operatorname{supp}(h_j f)$ contained in the $K \cap \operatorname{supp} (\varphi_j)$, hence a fortiori in every $\varepsilon$-neighbourhood of the latter. And by the argument above, for all sufficiently large $j$ we also have $K \cap \operatorname{supp}(\varphi_j)$ contained in the $\varepsilon$-neighbourhood of $K \cap \operatorname{supp} (h_j f) = K \cap \operatorname{supp}(f)$, thus convergence in the sense of the Hausdorff distance as desired.

But I don't know how to prove $\operatorname{supp}(h_j f) \subset \operatorname{supp}(\varphi_j)$. I don't see how it could be possible that the convolution vanishes identically on an open subset of $\operatorname{supp}(h_j f)$, but I cannot prove that it is impossible. Hence I modify $\varphi_j$ in such a way that the modified function $f_j$ is close enough to $\varphi_j$ that we still have convergence to $f$, and that $\operatorname{supp}(h_j f) \subset \operatorname{supp} (f_j)$. To that end, let $U$ be the interior of the set
$$\{ x \in \operatorname{supp}(h_j f) : \varphi_j(x) = 0\}\,.$$
Then take a function $\eta \in \mathscr{C}_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ with $U = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \eta(x) \neq 0\}$. The construction is similar to that of a partition of unity on $U$, but one needs to multiply the bump functions $\eta_m$ with a sufficiently fast decreasing coefficient sequence to have the series $\sum c_m \eta_m$ converge in $\mathscr{C}_c^{\infty}$. Multiplying $\eta$ with a small positive constant we can assume that all partial derivatives of order $\leqslant k$ of $\eta$ have modulus $\leqslant 1/j$ everywhere. Then put $f_j = \varphi_j + \eta$.

We have $\operatorname{supp} (f_j) = \operatorname{supp}(\varphi_j) \cup \operatorname{supp} (h_j f)$, and all partial derivatives of order $\leqslant k$ differ from the corresponding derivative of $h_j f$ by no more than $2/j$. Thus $f_j \to f$ in $\mathscr{C}^k(\Omega)$, and we have the desired convergence property for the supports.

Comment: Hi Daniel, this affirmation is on page 159 of the Trèves book. In proof that $K \cap \hbox{supp } f_j$  converges to $K \cap \hbox{supp  }f$.

Comment: I'm looking. Will take a while.

Comment: Hmm. Oof. I don't know if I can repair the proof. I don't know if that part of the assertion of Theorem 15.3 is correct (if it isn't, that probably doesn't matter, it's close enough). In any case, it's not as simple as replacing $K \cap \operatorname{supp}(f)$ with $\operatorname{supp}(f\lvert_K)$. But it's late today. Maybe I have something tomorrow.

Comment: It is not clear to me why the last statement ($x_0 \in U_\gamma$) is valid, more specifically, why $|f(x_0)|\geq \gamma$.

Comment: We need not have $\lvert f(x_0)\rvert \geqslant \gamma$. But there is a point $x_1 \in K$ with $\lvert f(x_1)\rvert = \gamma$ and $\lvert x_1 - x_0\rvert \leqslant \varepsilon/2 < \varepsilon$. Hence $$x_0 \in \{x_1\} + \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \lvert x\rvert < \varepsilon\} \subset U_{\gamma}\,.$$

Comment: Oh yes of course, I hadn't noticed. Thank you!

Comment: @VictorHugo I think I have fixed Trèves' proof.

Comment: Hi Daniel, sorry for the delay, I was trying to understand your proof.
I have two doubts at the end of the proof, the first one is how build the function $\eta$ (Is there any reference that makes this type of construction? It's the first time that I've seen something like that.) and the second one is how to proof that $\operatorname{supp} (f_j) = \operatorname{supp}(\varphi_j) \cup \operatorname{supp} (h_j f)$.

Comment: Re building $\eta$, look at the construction of partitions of unity (e.g. p. 161-165 here). Note that since $U$ is second countable every locally finite open cover of $U$ is countable, thus in Trèves' construction you can assume that $J = \mathbb{N}$. We consider an open cover by relatively compact sets of course. Then instead of $\sum \beta^j$, which is $1$ on $U$ and $0$ outside you consider $\sum c_j\beta^j$, where the coefficients $c_j > 0$ are chosen such that e.g. all partial derivatives of order $\leqslant j$ of $c_j\beta^j$ are bounded by $2^{-j}$. That ensures that $\sum c_j\beta^j$

Comment: converges in $\mathscr{C}_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Furthermore, $U = \{x : \eta(x) \neq 0\} = \{ x : \eta(x) > 0\}$, since each $x \in U$ lies in $\{x : \beta^j(x) > 0\}$ for some $j$ and all $\beta^j$ have support contained in $U$. Thus $\operatorname{supp}(\eta) = \overline{U}$. Since $\varphi_j$ vanishes on $U$, we have $$\operatorname{supp}(f_j) = \overline{\{x : f_j(x) \neq 0\}} = \overline{\{x : \varphi_j(x) \neq 0\} \cup \{x : \eta(x) \neq 0\}}\\ = \operatorname{supp}(\varphi_j) \cup \operatorname{supp}(\eta) = \operatorname{supp}(\varphi_j)\cup\overline{U}\,.$$

Comment: Hence $$\operatorname{supp}(\varphi_j) \subset \operatorname{supp}(f_j) \subset \operatorname{supp}(\varphi_j) \cup \overline{U} \subset \operatorname{supp}(\varphi_j) \cup \operatorname{supp}(h_j f)\,.$$ And if $x \in \operatorname{supp}(h_j f)$, then either $x \in \operatorname{supp}(\varphi_j)$, or $\varphi_j$ vanishes identically on some neighbourhood of $x$. But in the latter case $x \in U$. Therefore also $\operatorname{supp}(h_j f) \subset \operatorname{supp}(f_j)$.

Comment: I will reread the construction of the partition of unity. Just to confirm, will the function $\eta$ be the limit of $\sum c_j \beta^j$?

Comment: Yes, I take $\eta = \sum c_j\beta^j$. And to reiterate, we start with a countable open cover by relatively compact sets in order to get functions in $\mathscr{C}_c^{\infty}(U)$.

Comment: Hi Daniel! Some time later I went to type your answer and I was in doubt about one thing. How to show that $\operatorname{supp}(h_j f) \subset \operatorname{supp}(f_j)?$. We have that: $\operatorname{supp}(h_j f) \subset \operatorname{supp}(h_j f) \cap \operatorname{supp}(\varphi_j) \cup \operatorname{supp}(h_j f) \cap \complement \operatorname{supp}(\varphi_j) \subset \operatorname{supp}(\varphi_j) \cup \operatorname{supp}(h_j f) \cap \complement \operatorname{supp}(\varphi_j)$.

Comment: So, we have to show that $\operatorname{supp}(h_j f) \cap \complement \operatorname{supp}(\varphi_j) \subset U$, or equivalently, $\complement \operatorname{int}\{x \in \operatorname{supp}(h_j f): \phi_j(x)=0\} \subset \complement \operatorname{supp}(h_j f) \cup \operatorname{supp}(\phi_j)$.

Comment: Hence, $\complement \operatorname{int}\{x \in \operatorname{supp}(h_j f): \phi_j(x)=0\}= \overline{ \mathbb{R}^{n} \setminus \{x \in \operatorname{supp}(h_j f):\phi_j(x)=0 \}}=\overline{ \mathbb{R}^{n} \cap \complement(\operatorname{supp}(h_j f) \cap \varphi_j^{-1}(0) ) }=\overline{\complement \operatorname{supp}(h_j f) \cup \varphi_j^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^{n} \setminus \{0\}) }=\overline{\complement \operatorname{supp}(h_j f)} \cup \operatorname{supp}(\varphi_j)$.

Comment: I don't know how to conclude, can you help me?